# Why Unit is a supertype of anything else?

Tags: scala

Here's an example:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val a: Unit = 1
<console>:11: warning: a pure expression does nothing in statement position; you may be omitting necessary parentheses
       val a: Unit = 1
                     ^
a: Unit = ()
```

In Scala documentation:

```
There is only one value of type Unit, ()
```

Why is Scala compiler silently coercing values to Unit?

*A bit of context:* I used `Future[Unit]` type to describe some procedure which does not return anything. And since `Future[Unit]` is now effectively a subtype of `Unit`, I got bit by some funny bugs (`someFuture.map(a => Future(a))` silently skips calling the operation instead of giving compilation warning). What am I supposed to use as a type of operation that does not return any meaningful result?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Unit` is not a supertype of other types. What happens instead is called value discarding: when the expected type of an expression `e` is `Unit`, the compiler replaces it by `{e; ()}`. This is done to make some behavior more familiar. E.g.

```
val sb = new StringBuilder
val strings: List[String] = ...
for (str <- strings) { sb.append(str) }
```

By analogy with `for` loops in other languages, we would expect it to compile. But without value discarding it wouldn't: this is equivalent to `strings.foreach(str => sb.append(str))`, the type of `str => sb.append(str)` is `String => StringBuilder` (because all `append` methods on `StringBuilder` return the builder itself) and `foreach` on `List[String]` takes `String => Unit`.

You can add `-Ywarn-value-discard` compiler option to warn you when it happens (and write `for (sb <- sbOpt) { sb.append("a"); () }` explicitly).

Or you can actually go with [a trick](https://gist.github.com/puffnfresh/4465577) of defining your own `Unit` (possibly changing the name to avoid confusion for anyone reading your code):

```
 object Unit 
 type Unit = Unit.type 

 implicit def unit2scalaunit(a: Unit): scala.Unit = () 
 implicit def scalaunit2unit(a: scala.Unit): Unit = Unit
```

This should avoid running into the problem with `Future` you describe.

Comment: Defining my own unit is going to confuse the hell out of anyone forced to maintain my code afterwards :) But compiler warning is working great, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Unit` is *not* a supertype of everything! Scala actually has a pretty wide variety of conversions that happen automatically and this is one of them. From [section 6.26.1 **Value Conversions**](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#value-conversions) of the Scala language spec, one of the conversions is

> #### Value Discarding
>
> If `e` has some value type and the expected type is `Unit`, `e` is converted
>   to the expected type by embedding it in the term `{ e; () }`.

So when you write something like `val a: Unit = 1`, it gets processed into `val a: Unit = { 1; () }`, which is quite different. The warning is actually very helpful here - it is warning you that you probably did something wrong: the expression you are trying to put into statement position is pure (has no side-effects), so executing it has no effect (except possibly to cause the program to diverge) on the final output.

Comment: Warning is helpful indeed, but it doesn't happen most of the time - if expression is not pure, it just discards the result silently.

Comment: @Rogach I hesitate to say the result is never discarded, but it certainly is not always discarded. Just try something like `val x: Unit = { println("hi"); 1 } + 2`. The result of the operation (`3`) is discarded, but `"hi"` _is_ printed. What is your particular example?

Comment: The _result_ is always discarded.

Comment: Futures. When you do `val futA: Future[A] = ???; futA.map(a => Future(a))` the second future operation is never executed, since nothing depends on it.

Comment: @Rogach I must be misunderstanding something - do you have a small runnable example in mind? `Future(1).map(a => { println("hi"); a + 1 })` works as expected, executing the second future and printing `"hi"`.

Comment: @Alec - it's a confusion on my end. The operation runs fine, but exceptions (which can be considered a form of result of the Future) are swallowed - which is about as bad as not running operation at all.